# MongoDB returning empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate albums with images using userid sent through params but i end up with an empty array even though there is data in database.

```
"use strict"
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

console.log('Welcome');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Datab');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected to Database');

});

//Schema for the data 

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
var albumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid: String,
    albumName: String,
    albumDesc: String,
    albumThumbnail: String,
    imageCount: Number,
    images: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Image'
    }]
});

var ImageSchema = new Schema({
    album_id: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Album'
    },
    imageName: String,
    imageDescription: String,
    imageURL: String,
    likeCount: Number,
    commentCount: Number
})


var Userdata = mongoose.model('Userdata', userSchema);
var Album = mongoose.model('Album', albumSchema);
var Image = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);

//display of albums
app.get('/user/:user_id/photos', function (req, res) {
    var user_id = req.params.user_id
    Album.find({
        userid: user_id
    })
        .populate('images')
        .exec(function (err, albums) {
            if (!err) {
                return res.send({
                    status: {
                        error: 0,
                        message: "Successful"
                    },
                    data: {
                        albums: albums
                    }
                })
            } else
                res.send('Unsuccessful');
        })


});


app.listen(3000);
```

output:

```
{

    "status": {

        "error": 0,

        "message": "Successful"

    },

    "data": {

        "albums": []

    }

}
```

why do i get an empty array as output?

Find in the mongo shell returns the following result

```
db.Album.find() {
    "_id": ObjectId("529eed506c7b0a09b2204203"),
    "albumDesc": "outings",
    "albumName": "Photoclics1",
    "albumThumbnail": "http: //192.168.71.250/uploads/cat1_thumb.jpg",
    "imageCount": "1",
    "images": ["529ef0016c7b0a09b2204205", "529ef0266c7b0a09b2204206"],
    "userid": "529eec5a6c7b0a09b22041ff"
}
```

EDIT 2: This is the output that i expect to get

```
{
"error": {
"status": 0,
"message": "Successful"
},
"data": {
"albums": [
{
"albumName": "myclicks",
"albumID": "527102fdaed86d8807000001",
"albumDescription": "PhotosIclicked",
"albumThumbnailURL": "http: //192.168.71.250/uploads/image.jpg",
"imageCount": 2,
"images": [
{
"imageID": "527102fdaed86d8807000001",
"imageName": "mycat",
"imageDescription": "billy",
"imageURL": "http: //192.168.71.250/uploads/cat.jpg",
"imageThumbnailURL": "http: //192.168.71.250/uploads/cat_thumb.jpg",
"likeCount": 21,
"commentCount": 1
},
{
"imageID": "527102fdaed86d8807000001",
"imageName": "mycat",
"imageDescription": "billy",
"imageURL": "http: //192.168.71.250/uploads/cat1.jpg",
"imageThumbnailURL": "http: //192.168.71.250/uploads/cat1_thumb.jpg",
"likeCount": 21,
"commentCount": 1
}
]
}
]
}
```

Comment: If you run  simple find in the mongo shell on albums what data do you get?

Comment: The code is not readable. I'm sure you can format it better!

Comment: @hgoebl Formatted the code

Comment: Thanks, I can read it, but I don't know an answer, sorry. Looks good IMO.

Comment: Did you check if you parsed user_id correctly?

Comment: Just to make it sure, you're getting an empty albums array so the images array does not matter concerning your problem?

Comment: @Xinzz yes i have parsed it properly

Comment: @Saintedlama yes it matters, its the part of the output. Please check my edited question (EDIT 2). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identifier stored in the `images` array is shown as a String in the console. Yet, the definition in the schema for the `images` field is shown as the type `ObjectId`. If you either fix the data to be an `ObjectId` or change the data type, the issue should be resolved.

You could fix the data in the MongoDB console by iterating through the collection and the array and converting each element to an `ObjectId`.